# Obtaining compiler include (and linker library) search paths for C code with JNI portably

Tags: c++, c, build, java-native-interface

I have a shared C library, `libfoo.so`, for which I'm creating a JNI interface. In order to compile the JNI interface library, `libfoojni.so`, compiler include search paths must be specified. For example, on Linux (using GCC) the following compiler flags are required: `-I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux`.

Unfortunately, the latter path includes the platform. On SunOS the latter path is `-I${JAVA_HOME}/include/solaris`, on AIX it is `-I${JAVA_HOME}/include/aix`, and on HP-UX it's `-I${JAVA_HOME}/include/hp-ux`. This is a nuisance in the build files.

Is there a way to obtain the include paths portably? For example, with perl, you can use `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts` to obtain the compiler flags and `-e ldopts` the linker flags, respectively. I'm looking for something similar to this, but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not a Java or JNI question at all.

The normal way to address this is to use something like the autoconf / automake tool chain which create Make files and 'configure' scripts that run on a wide range of platforms.

Comment: I've removed the java tag but kept the jni one, since people doing JNI have probably bumped into this issue.